# apache requests failing

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, request

I'm trying to figure out why sometimes the client fails to load objects/requests from a dynamic page served from **Apache/MySql/Debian** machine.

Let's say **13** objects are to be loaded for a total of **185.3 KB** load, with no external objects (no DNS lookups) and no other traffic at the same time, randomly some of those object do not load. However, if I perform a refresh, sometimes all of them load or some might fail again. I only have **1Mbps/up** and my DNS is been hosted externally (everydns).

What could be the reason of this issue? Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to track a lot more data.  If your browser has developer extensions so you can track the status of all the various requests, that would be one way of figuring out what's going on.  Another, and my first choice, would be looking over some tcpdump/wireshark dumps. Even log data would be useful.  Without *some* idea what's happening, you can't even blame this on Apache yet.

Answer (score 0):

might not be the best way to track requests but you could try Firebug and Network Monitoring

http://getfirebug.com/network

Comment: BTW lower than that not quite sure...